# calling a variable from outside a callback nodejs

Tags: node.js, glob

im using glob from npm

```
gl = require("glob");
get = {};
gl("path/to/files/*.rmd", {}, function(err, files){
     get.files = files
 });
console.log(get.files)

output: undefined
```

what im trying to do is get access to the files from outside its callback. But, everything I try isn't working.

Comment: Did you try to console.log into your callback the content of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use glob.sync which can be used to make a synchronous call

```
gl = require("glob");
let get = {};
get['files']=gl.sync("path/to/files/*.rmd", {});
console.log(get.files)
```

Ref: [sync call glob.sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#globsyncpattern-options)

Answer (score 1):

Referencing an outside variable from an inner function is perfectly acceptable, heck it's what makes JS so special. It's called closure.

But the problem is `glob` is `asynchronous`, means it will run `console.log` before completing the actual glob search.

So what you can do is you can `console.log` it inside the callback. Or make a promise out of it and console.log in the `then` function. Or you can maybe use `async/await` and await the function.

```
const gl = require("glob");
const get = {};
gl("./*.js", {}, function(err, files){
     get.files = files
     console.log(get);
});
// OR
const glP = function(){
    return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
        gl("./*.js", {}, function(err, files){
            if(err) rej(err);
            res(files);
       });
    })
}

glP()
.then((files)=>{
    get.files = files;
    console.log(get);
})

// OR
(async ()=>{
    const files = await glp();
    get.files = files;
    console.log(get);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of `async` nature of the callbacks, your `console.log(get.files)` will get called before the callback function of glob() has been called. The answers above are good. I am going to add one more answer to it.

```
'use strict';

const glob = require('glob');
const bluebird = require('bluebird');

const globPromise = bluebird.promisify(glob);
let get = {};
globPromise("./files/*.rmd", {})
  .then((files) => {
    console.log(files);
    get.files = files;
    console.log(get.files);
  });
```

Above code `Promisify` the whole `glob` NPM Package and provides you with an ability to perform asynchronous tasks. In your own code either you should write your console.log() inside the callback function or you can use Promises which will make sure that you would get called once `glob` does it's job.